# Highscore List using Vector in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vector

I just update the code to show my newer, recent update on my Highscore List trying to use a Vector. I took out the vector statement, but I know this right here, works perfectly with writing and reading from a text file. ATTENTION- Any new readers I updated this code for one person can observe my newer code

```
// Get the scores from the game
int getHighscore()
{
    ShowConsoleCursor(true);
    HANDLE hOut;
    hOut = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
    fstream file;
    file.open("Highscores.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    if(file.good()==true) {
        string TextLimit;
        TextLimit = charLimit();
        file << TextLimit;
        for(int a=0; a<=40-TextLimit.length(); a++) {
            file<<" ";
            }
            file<<Killed<<endl;
            file.close();
        }
        ShowConsoleCursor(false);
        return 0;
}

// Displays the scores from the game
void HighscoreResults()
{
    system("cls");
    fstream file;
    file.open("Highscores.txt", ios::in);
    if(file.good()==true)
    {
        string p1Name;
        SetColor(11);
        CPos(1,15); cout << "  _   _ _       _                                      \n";
        CPos(2,15); cout << " | | | (_) __ _| |__  ___  ___ ___  _ __ ___  ___      \n";
        CPos(3,15); cout << " | |_| | |/ _` | '_ \\/ __|/ __/ _ \\| '__/ _ \\/ __|  \n";
        CPos(4,15); cout << " |  _  | | (_| | | | \\__ \\ (_| (_) | | |  __/\\__ \\ \n";
        CPos(5,15); cout << " |_| |_|_|\\__, |_| |_|___/\\___\\___/|_|  \\___||___/  \n";
        CPos(6,15); cout << "          |___/                                        \n";
        CPos(7,10); SetColor(10);
        cout << " ------------------------------------------------------------";
        CPos(9,15); SetColor(14);
        cout << " Names:\n";
        CPos(9,50);
        cout << " Zombies Killed:\n"; SetColor(15);
        while(getline(file, p1Name))
        {
            cout << "                 " << p1Name << endl;
        }
        file.close();
   }
    else
    {
        cout<<"The file cannot open!";
        system("pause >nul");
    }
}

// Makes where only a 8 char can be entered when entering a name
string charLimit()
{
    int characters=-1;
    char text[10];
    int Button;
    string TextLimit;
    while(true)
    {
        // Clears the name when backspaced
        CPos(20, 13);
        cout<<"                      ";
        CPos(20, 13);
        cout<<" Name: ";
        // Puts a limit on the characters of the text
        for(int a=0; a<=characters; a++)
        {
            cout<<text[a];
        }
        Button = getch();
    if(Button==13 && characters>0)
    {
        for(int a=0; a<=characters; a++)
        {
            if(text[a]!=' ') TextLimit = TextLimit + text[a];
        }
            return TextLimit;
        }
        if(Button==8 && characters>=0)
        {
            text[characters] = ' ';
            characters--;
        }
        else if(Button!=8 && characters+1<=9)
        {
            characters++;
            text[characters] = Button;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output? Where does the vector get sorted? Seems like there is only 1 item inside the vector.

Comment: @qamyoncu The output in the void HighscoreResults(); and along with the vector, I'm still new to them and I'm very confused on how to use one inside a text document.

Comment: @ProgrammerRyan98 What is the type of Killed?

Comment: @furkle Killed should be int Killed = 0;

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the vector before you save it. The [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) method can be used for your purposes like so:

```
std::sort (SS.begin(), SS.end());
```

This will sort SS in place. If you want to keep SS in an out-of-order sense, you should create a copy of it first and then sort the copy. (Though I'm not sure why you'd ever want to have high scores in an out-of-order vector.)

You have a comment suggesting that you're sorting the kill values somewhere, but it doesn't appear that ever gets done.

Also, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do when you fill your vector. You haven't included the type of Killed (though I am assuming it's an int, because you'd get a compiler error otherwise upon trying to add it to your vector), but you only push_back that single int to SS a single time in your code.

Based on your new edit, I think you're using the high scores text file in the wrong fashion. You don't appear to be really keeping reference to the high scores for the course of the game. Rather, you append the result of each game to the file, then print the contents of the file as the high score. Here's how I think you should do this:

1. Read the high scores at the beginning of the program, storing each in a `Score` struct with string or char[] name and int kills. Store each of these in a vector class field. Sort this vector from greater to lesser after it's populated. (This will require you to implement a comparer for your `std::sort()` call, so look at the guide I linked you.)
2. When a player's game ends, construct a Score and add it to the `vector<Score>`. If you want to have a max number of scores on the board (which you probably should), you should check if the last element in the `vector` (e.g. the `Score` object with the least kills) has less kills than the most recent playthrough. If it does, remove the last element, add a `Score` object for the current game, and sort again. Blank the score file and iterate through your `vector<Score>`, writing the name and kills on a line.

As it stands, your SS vector isn't even going to be able to hold the players' names.

Comment: So should I delete my whole vector inside my code and perhaps put this where it says getHighscore? or HighscoreResults? Basically save it into a vector first? or save it into a vector after the scores are called?

Comment: @ProgrammerRyan98 Well, one of the problems you have is that you don't appear to ever be writing to the high scores text file. Did you omit that section?

Comment: No it does write into a text file, trust me. it works perfectly

Comment: @ProgrammerRyan98 The problem is that you haven't actually included the way you're keeping track of all the high scores you've pulled from the file. Where is it stored? Where is it loaded? You should be loading all the high scores into your vector at some point, sorting it after load, sorting it again when you add a new value to it at the end of a game, rewriting your high score file with the state of your vector.

Comment: Here I just updated the code without the vector statement inside, this is what I'm using right now in my project and this works for writing and reading from the text document! Maybe this can help?

Comment: Forget the whole SS vector, but the names won't be able to match up with the zombies Killed score? and I know it's wrong to ask, and I know I need to try this all on my own and which I have. But I'm still a beginner in my Highschool C++ class and we have't even learned Vectors yet! and no, this isn't a project for a grade but I'm doing this in spite of fun. I know it's wrong but do you think you could show me an example or give me a template to build my code off of? I'm just so new to these vectors and have no clue where to start and honestly how to sort it into a vector first.

Comment: @ProgrammerRyan98 I can try - my C++ syntax is a little bit rustier than my fundamentals, so it might have some pseudocode where I don't feel like ensuring it's copy-pastable, and there might be some minor errors. I'll see if I get a chance in a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, you don't know how much I appreciate it, I'll add you to my credits in my C++ game, which I'll probably be posting to youtube! You honestly do not honestly how appreciative I am if you can help me out. And heck, maybe I can show you my C++ game when it's finished?:)

Comment: By any chance, should I make a class player{
   string name;
   int score;
}

vector<player> players; ?

Comment: I guess you're done helping me? Just let me know if so, I understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
class player{
   string name;
   int score;
}

vector<player> players;
```

You didn't sort the list. You need to sort the vector before you store it. So every time you `push_back` an item, you will need to sort again using `std::sort();`.

Comment: How would I put that in my vector? in front of the backing? I'm just totally confused on the whole thing

Comment: It seems that what you want to do is let the user type in a 8-char name and then get the highest score from game, then store this two pairs into the file. Is this correct?

Comment: Almost!, I want it to maybe display the top ten highscores, but you were right about able to get a 8-char name. But then I want it to display the scores in distending order from highest score to lowest.

Comment: If you want to display just top ten highscores, you can have 2 vectors at the beginning of the game, read in the file and store the information into the vectors. one of them store the sorted scores. one of them store the according name.(namely that the index of score vector and name vector for the same player should be the same.) then, you start the game. when it's finished, you have a pair of name and score for this specific player. Then you push_back the score, then call std::sort(scoreVector.begin(), scoreVector.end()) to sort the vector

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm just really new to vectors and everything, I'm currently enrolled in a C++ class in my Highschool and I'm making a game, out of fun, and It would be awesome if it had a highscore list! It's just I'm so confused on how to use vectors still, we haven't even learned them in class. I know it's wrong to ask but do you think you can help build a template with my code including the vectors? If give me some kind of big lead?

Comment: after you read my edited answer above(which I haven't finished yet), you will find a problem. if we want the names to be in the right order, we kind of need to track the way the scores are sorted. But because that we call the library method to let it sort by itself, we can not track the process.  So I think to use a hash table instead of 2 vectors will be a better solution.

Comment: I'll check it out once it's updated! But thank you so much for your help, you don't understand how much I appreciate it. And just for learning purposes, what is a hash table? and what does it do?

Comment: actually you can do this, why not have a name-score data structure, then you store the object into a vector, then sorted it using the order of score, then you can maintain the same order for score and as well as name

Comment: I just have no clue where to start, just like I said I'm new to vectors and all the research I know about them has been through online and not in my class! I am just so stumped on the whole thing!

Comment: How would I apply that and where in my overall code? *FYI - I updated my code if you didn't notice!*